# Exception on pressing the back button of emulator Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am creating an  application where the first activity calls the second activity for results i.e `startActivityForResult(intent,SELECT_FILE);` but on going to second activity if i press the back button of my emulator it throws a exception :

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.upload/com.upload.FileUploadActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

what should i do..?

Thankx

Comment: paste more code from your FileUploadActivity, where you set the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start a new activity using `startActivityForResult` a result is expected when the new activity ends. Normally the new activity is ended and the result is defined in the `finish()` method.

What I suspect is happening is you do not process the back button press in the new activity and as such no result is generated. Then when the 'onActivityResult()`is called in the old activity there is no activity to process and you are getting the`NullPointerException`.

You can solve this one of two ways.

In the new activity Listen for the back button press and when it is pressed call `finish()` to setup the result. Or in the old activity check the result to make sure it is valid and isn't null (You should really be doing this anyway)